# How to divide a hexa-decimal number in masm 8086 so as to get the remainder?

Tags: assembly, hex, masm, x86-16, divide

I want to convert a hexadecimal number to its corresponding ASCII. For doing so, I need to get every digit from my input and and convert to its corresponding ASCII. I know this can be done in decimal by just dividing and getting the remainder in ah, but i am facing problem doing this in Hexadecimal. Any Help?

Comment: It works for any base, of course. However division by 16 is easily accomplished by bit shifting and masking since computers use binary. But `DIV` works too.

Comment: When you say that you want to convert a hexadecimal number to ASCII, in what form do you have that number? If it actually was a number represented in hexadecimal, it would already be text.

Comment: Although the division could be accomplished by bit shifting, there is still a need for the remainder of %16

Comment: what did you tried till now? edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

As for decimal you can repeatedly divide by the needed base, this is 16. The problem is, that you cannot get as easy the hexadecimal characters, because the ASCII table is not continuos at this point:

> '0' => 30h
>   ...
>   '9' => 39h
>   **GAP**
>   'A' => 41h
>   ...
>   'F' => 46h

To get e.g. an 'A' from the remainder 10, you have to add 7 **after** the conversion to ASCII. Example:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 1000h

.DATA

    number dw 09A8Fh
    hexstring db 4 DUP (?)
    last_hex EQU ($ - 1)
    terminator db '$'

.CODE

main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov cx, 16              ; Base 16 (hexadecimal)
    mov di, last_hex
    mov ax, number

    L1:
    xor dx, dx              ; Don't forget it!
    div cx
    or dl, 30h              ; Convert remainder to ASCII
    cmp dl, '9'
    jbe @F                  ; Jump to next @@
    add dl, 7               ; Adjust ASCII
    @@:
    mov [di], dl            ; Store ASCII
    dec di                  ; Move DI backwards
    test ax, ax             ; AX == 0?
    jne L1                  ; No: once more

    lea dx, hexstring
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```